# Second DIV won't align, gets pushed down

Tags: html, css, alignment

I search everywhere and tried everything I could, but I cannot make my second DIV align. See code below:

[image on tinypic.com](http://tinypic.com/r/2z6e5pz/5)

As you can see, I have added a white border so that we can see the exact size. The problem here is with the social media buttons DIV on the right.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="content_header">
    <div id="schcontainer" class="schcontainer">
        <%= form_tag({:controller => 'list', :action => 'index'}, :id => 'searchfrm') do %>
            <div id="searchboxwrap">
                <%= text_field_tag(:query, value=@query, options={:size => "47", :placeholder => "Enter a product name..."}) %>
                <%= text_field_tag(:selectedpage, value=@page, options={:class => "hiddenelement"}) %>
            </div>
            <%= submit_tag("") %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>   
    <div id="mediabuttons">
        <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div>
        <div><a href="https://twitter.com/share" data-url="<%=renderFullUrl%>" data-count="horizontal" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="small">Tweet</a></div>
        <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
        <div><script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right"></script></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" id="fb-root"></div>
```

And here's the CSS

```
#content_header{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height:35px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#schcontainer{
   width:48%;
   border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;   
}

#mediabuttons{
    width:39%;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
}

#mediabuttons div{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}


.clear {
   height: 0;
   font-size: 1px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   line-height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

**UPDATED CSS:**

```
#content_header{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I prefer to use `display:inline-block` as opposed to floats when possible and now seems to be one of those times. Replacing the floats with these on the two primary divs should do the trick. Your tinypic images aren't working for me but try this jsfiddle and see if it's producing the results you are looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/k96BU/

I added a `vertical-align:top` so they would be lined up properly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `float: left` to your `#schcontainer` should fix the issue. You might have to had `overflow: hidden` or some kind of clearfix to your `#content_header` afterward though.

Comment: [link] (http://tinypic.com/r/xlgzlg/5) I added float:left, removed height, and also added overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 0):

`#schcontainer` wants `float:left` surely?

Comment: [link] (http://tinypic.com/r/xlgzlg/5) I added float:left, removed height, and also added overflow:hidden.